# Fallback function using ellipsis: can we force the size of the parameters pack?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, variadic-functions

Consider the following code:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    template<typename T, typename... A>
    auto f(A&&... args) -> decltype(std::declval<T>().f(std::forward<A>(args)...), void()) {
        std::cout << "has f(int)" << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename>
    void f(...) {
        std::cout << "has not f(int)" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct T { void f(int) { } };
struct U { };

int main() {
    S s;
    s.f<T>(42); // -> has f(int)
    s.f<U>(42); // -> has not f(int)
    // oops
    s.f<T>(); // -> has not f(int)
}
```

As shown in the example the third call to `f` works just fine, even if the number of arguments is *wrong*, for it's not wrong at all for the fallback function.

Is there a way to force the number of arguments when an ellipsis is involved that way?
I mean, can I check at compile time that the size of the arguments list is exactly `1`, no matter if the main function or the fallback is chosen?

Good solutions are also the ones that only involves the first template function and result in hard-errors instead of soft-errors because of the size of the parameter pack.

---

Of course, it can be solved with several techniques without using variadic arguments. As an example: `int`/`char` dispatching on internal template methods; explicitly specify the arguments list; whatever...
The question is not about alternative approaches to do that, I already know them.
It's just to know if I'm missing something basic here or it's not possible and that's all.

Comment: ...why exactly do you need this? One would think that forcing end users to pass dummy arguments is terrible API design.

Comment: @T.C. Fair enough. I was trying something with a colleague and the doubt arose. Just curious, it is not meant for production software. The real problem is bigger and not suitable for a better example to be post on SO.

Comment: `Is there a way to force the number of arguments when an ellipsis is involved that way?`: Not really, no. Variadic args have only `va_start`, `va_end`, and `va_list` operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your issue, you may add a layer:

```
struct S {
private:
    template<typename T, typename... A>
    auto f_impl(A&&... args)
    -> decltype(std::declval<T>().f(std::forward<A>(args)...), void()) {
        std::cout << "has f(int)" << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename>
    void f_impl(...) {
        std::cout << "has not f(int)" << std::endl;
    }
public:

    template<typename T, typename A>
    auto f(A&& args) { return f_impl<T>(std::forward<A>(arg)); }
};
```

With traits, you may do

```
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
using f_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().f(std::declval<Ts>()...));

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
using has_f = is_detected<f_t, T, Ts...>;

struct S {
    template<typename T, typename... A>
    std::enable_if_t<has_f<T, A&&...>::value && sizeof...(A) == 1> f(A&&... args)
    {
        std::cout << "has f(int)" << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename T, typename... A>
    std::enable_if_t<!has_f<T, A&&...>::value && sizeof...(A) == 1>  f(A&&... args) {
        std::cout << "has not f(int)" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ac4530d1548abdd)

Comment: ... and check in that layer the size of the parameters  pack, right. It works, but I'm wondering if there exists a solution that does not require me to define a new function.

Comment: Here, currently, I fixed the argument count directly in f. If you create a traits, you may have 2 variadic method and check size with SFINAE.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but it can work. thank you.

Comment: I'm talking about something like: [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ac4530d1548abdd)

Comment: As I said, it's not exactly what I was looking for, but I'd accept the answer if you add that code to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can  use a function  (assert) that gets  pointer to a function to deduce size of paramemters :

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
template <typename...Args>
struct size_assert{
    template <typename T,typename R,typename... Params>
    constexpr static bool assert(R(T::*)(Params...) )
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Args) == sizeof...(Params),"Incorrect size of arguments!");
        return true;
    }
};

struct S {

    template<typename T, typename... A, bool =  size_assert<A...>::assert(&T::f)>
    auto f(A&&... args) -> decltype(std::declval<T>().f(std::forward<A>(args)...), void()) 

    {
        std::cout << "has f(int)" << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename>
    void f(...) {
        std::cout << "has not f(int)" << std::endl;
    }
};


struct T { void f(int) { } };
struct U { };

int main() {
   // std::cout <<fc(&f);
    S s;
    s.f<T>(42); // -> has f(int)
    s.f<U>(42); // -> has not f(int)
    // oops
    s.f<T>(); // -> has not f(int)
}
```